# OpenCL/GPU/CUDA support under WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, opencl, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I read that this almost impossible right now to use the GPU under WSL2 (Ubuntu-20.04 distro), but NVidia has some tutorials using docker (my GPU is nVidia 960m) which I am not interested in at all.

I would like to use OpenCL only for CLI applications under WSL2/Windows 10. **CLinfo** reports 0 platforms, which means it can not detect my GPU. So, Is there any way to enable OpenCL just for CLI applications?

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

Also the command below returns nothing

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6951 - Doesn't look implemented yet.

Comment: @nelsonjchen yeap, it seems like that, thanx